# Как задать определённое сообщение в переменную? JavaScript, Discord.js

Tags: javascript

Я хочу чтоб бот определённое сообщение брал в переменную. 
К примеру кто то написал "Привет!" и бот сохранил это сообщение в переменную.

Comment: И что дальше с этой переменной должно происходить?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать подобным образом.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return
    let variable = message.content
});
```